# SWIFT 13.1 como guardar el estado de un UIButton en un tableView con UserDefaults?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

estoy haciendo una vista de una lista con persistencia de datos usando `UserDefaults` , la lista ya funciona, cuando cierro mi app y la vuelvo a abrir siguen estando los datos ahi o cuando elimino una celda del table view permanecen los dados que dejo, en cada uno de los elementos de mi lista aparece un boton el cual hace función de un checkbox pero no logro guardar el estado de cada uno de los botones. ya que al momento de recuperar el estado del boton me pone `true` para todos o `false` para todos.

aqui mi codigo del `UIButton`

```
class CheckBox: UIButton {

    //MARK: - imagenes y propiedades para el checkBox
    let checkedImage = UIImage(named: "checked_checkbox")!
    let unCheckedImage = UIImage(named: "unchecked_checkbox")!

    @IBInspectable var isChecked = false {
        didSet {
            if isChecked == true {
                self.setImage(checkedImage, for: .normal)
            } else {
                self.setImage(unCheckedImage, for: .normal)
            }
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CheckBox.buttonClicked), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
        self.isChecked = false
    }

    @objc func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        if (sender == self) {
            if isChecked == true {
                isChecked = false
            } else {
                isChecked = true
            }
        }
        UserDefaults.standard.set(isChecked, forKey: "estado")
        print(UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "estado"))

    }

}
```

Comment: Abel el userdefaults funciona como un unico diccionario de datos con una key y un dato. En tu caso estas guardando un bool en una key llamada "estado" y sin importar desde que boton la llames siempre estas accediendo al mismo "estado", siempre guardas en la misma key.

Comment: asi es @ErickSilva por eso esta el print ahi para verificar que si guarda el dato y precisamente busco como hacer pueda guardar el estado para cada boton que se agregue y no solo el estado de la variable booleana ya que esta siempre me pondra el mismo valor para todos los botones

Comment: Bien! entonces guarda un Array de diccionarios donde cada diccionario contenga una key y un bool. La key sera el Id del modelo al que corresponde esa celda y el bool sera el valor de isChecked que corresponda.
Sino podrias agregar una propiedad que sea isChecked en tu modelo directamente y que se guarde junto a los otros datos

Comment: Un poco tarde ya pero lo que debes hacer es añadir un campo booleano a tu arreglo del cual llenas el tableView y e. Cell for row preguntas por el estado del bolleano según el Indexpath y co. Eso ya tienes el estado del botón salvado